# Error installing bassmaster 1.5.1

Tags: programming

Node version: v18.13.0
npm version: 8.19.3

I have my **awae** material and I want to install the vulnerable **bassmasster** version 1.5.1 on my computer

Error:

```
settings.routes = Config.enable(settings.routes);
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'routes' on string '3000'
    at internals.setup (/home/sabya/Bug bounty/Bassmaster/node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js:595:21)
    at new module.exports.internals.Core (/home/sabya/Bug bounty/Bassmaster/node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js:54:46)
    at new module.exports (/home/sabya/Bug bounty/Bassmaster/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:22:18)
    at internals.main (/home/sabya/Bug bounty/Bassmaster/node_modules/bassmaster/examples/batch.js:65:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sabya/Bug bounty/Bassmaster/node_modules/bassmaster/examples/batch.js:88:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

I get this error every time I run the `examples/batch.js` although I expect the server to start.

Comment: This isn't a security question at all.